# Unable to get terminal prompt when executing script via ssh

Tags: ssh, command-line, terminal, tty, prompt

I have the below script that works fine when run locally

cat /tmp/input.sh

```
                echo -n ">> "
                read env
                exit;
```

I get the command prompt when i run as below.

```
$/tmp/input.sh | echo "whatever"
$
```

All good so far. The problem occurs when i run this script via ssh

```
ssh wladmin@myhost /tmp/input.sh | echo "whatever"

This system is for the use by authorized users only. All data contained
on all systems is owned by the company and may be monitored, intercepted,
recorded, read, copied, or captured in any manner and disclosed in any
manner, by authorized company personnel. Users (authorized or unauthorized)
have no explicit or implicit expectation of privacy. Unauthorized or improper
use of this system may result in administrative, disciplinary action, civil
and criminal penalties. Use of this system by any user, authorized or
unauthorized, constitutes express consent to this monitoring, interception,
recording, reading, copying, or capturing and disclosure.

IF YOU DO NOT CONSENT, LOG OFF NOW.

##################################################################
# *** This Server is using Centrify                          *** #
# *** Remember to use your Active Directory account          *** #
# ***    password when logging in                            *** #
##################################################################
```

As you see i expected control on the command prompt terminal i.e `$` but unless i press `Crtl + C` or others i do not get the command prompt to type further.

I tried `ssh -T`  option but that did not help.

Can you suggest what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

The `echo "whatever"` is killing the script at the `echo -n ">> "` line, since it is not accepting any input coming from the script - therefore the `read env` never happens. I do not see why you would be doing `|echo` like that but carrying on regardless - When you do the ssh, only the input.sh script gets run remotely - and it does not "know" that text to stdout will be rejected. To get the same effect, run everything remotely, i.e. quote or escape the `|`

```
ssh wladmin@myhost /tmp/input.sh \| echo "whatever"
```

Comment: The purpose of `| echo` is to feed input to the `read env`. I don't know if there is a better way to do that?

Comment: its using `ksh` shell. i tried your solution but i get the below error.  `+ exec /usr/share/centrifydc/libexec/ssh wladmin@myhost  '|' echo whatever                                 
ksh: syntax error at line 1: '`| unexpected
`

Comment: It's a typo - you dropped the /tmp/input.sh script

Comment: To feed the echo to the script, it needs to be in front, and then the local or remote won't matter either. So `echo "whatever" | ssh wladmin@myhost /tmp/input.sh`